# Error in Gradle build in Android Studio v1.1.0

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to make a simple programming assignment in Android Studio, but when I created the project it's giving me this error:

> Executing tasks: [:app:generateDebugSources,
>   :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources]
>
> Configuration on demand is an incubating feature. :app:preBuild
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE :app:checkDebugManifest
>   :app:prepareDebugDependencies :app:compileDebugAidl
>   :app:compileDebugRenderscript :app:generateDebugBuildConfig
>   :app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE :app:mergeDebugAssets
>   :app:generateDebugResValues :app:generateDebugResources
>   :app:mergeDebugResources Exception while processing task 
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: AAPT process not ready to receive commands
>     at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.crunch(AaptProcess.java:75)
>     at
>   com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$2.run(QueuedCruncher.java:157)
>     at com.android.builder.tasks.Job.runTask(Job.java:46)   at
>   com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.runTask(QueuedCruncher.java:108)
>     at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:209)  at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Exception while processing task 
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: AAPT process not ready to receive commands
>     at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.crunch(AaptProcess.java:75)
>     at
>   com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$2.run(QueuedCruncher.java:157)
>     at com.android.builder.tasks.Job.runTask(Job.java:46)   at
>   com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.runTask(QueuedCruncher.java:108)
>     at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:209)  at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Exception while processing task 
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: AAPT process not ready to receive commands
>     at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.crunch(AaptProcess.java:75)
>     at
>   com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$2.run(QueuedCruncher.java:157)
>     at com.android.builder.tasks.Job.runTask(Job.java:46)   at
>   com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.runTask(QueuedCruncher.java:108)
>     at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:209)  at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) :app:mergeDebugResources FAILED
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
>
>   > Crunching Cruncher ic_launcher.png failed, see logs
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>
> BUILD FAILED
>
> Total time: 1 mins 18.135 secs

Please help me in resolving this issue. I am running Android Studio version 1.1.0.

Comment: Why are you still using AS 1.1.0? it's really old

Comment: try to invalidate Caches/Restart.Hope,it help you to resolve your problem.

Comment: @Peter I'm using it on an old PC with Windows 7 (32-bit) installed on it that's why. And Eclipse IDE is not supported anymore.

Comment: how can I do this, can you please guide me @UchihaSasuke?

Comment: @AbdulBasitMehtab Go to FIle->Invalidate Cache/Restart. Let me know .

Comment: Seems there is an issue with one of your images `ic_launcher.png`. Check if it is ok.

Comment: It's solved now, I've tried Invalidate Cache/Restart, and it worked perfectly.

Comment: @AbdulBasitMehtab Good to hear, it work.Look into answer for more detail.Accept answer, so it may help to others.

Answer (score 1):

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> Executing tasks: [:app:generateDebugSources,
>   :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources]

Most of the time this type of error can be handle with help of

1. Invalidate Caches/Restart:- It will help to reset Your resource file.
2. Restart your OS :- It will help to integrate hardware with Android Studio.

*as @Henry and @jdv suggested*

3.Check the resource it is complaining about to make sure it is actually a valid PNG or not.

Cheers.

Comment: I would add: 3. Check the resource it is complaining about to make sure it is actually a valid PNG or whatever. There are online tools to validate images.